# Нейросеть и обработка изображений

Tags: изображения

Предположим, что я хочу передать черно-белое изображение нейросети (10,000 входных нейронов, разрешение 100x100). Как я могу осуществить это с изображениями с разным соотношением сторон? Я вижу три варинта:

*1. Обрезать у изображения "лишнее", чтобы привести к квадрату (этот вариант сразу отпадает)*

*2. Ресайзнуть картинку до 100x100, не обращая внимание на соотношение сторон*

*3. Вместить картинку в квадрат, сохранив соотношение сторон. Оставшиеся свободные пиксели залить черным цветом.*

Каков из вариантов предпочтительнее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зависит от задачи и сети. На готовой сети лучше всего использовать тот метод, на который сеть была тренирована (отсюда же и вопрос: как была тренирована сеть на неквадратных изображениях?)

Преимущества и недостатки каждого подхода:

1. Отрезать лишнее:

   - помогает убрать шум, если вы знаете, что может быть лишним на изображении; сохраняет пропорции
   - может убрать ключевую для сети информацию (и вы не знаете, какую)
2. Ресайз:

   - прост, часто используется для приведения к стандартному виду, есть несколько вариантов самого ресайза и пост-обработки
   - искажает пропорции и углы, может убрать ключевую информацию (например, при уменьшении потеряются точки) или добавить лишнюю
3. Вместить в квадрат:

   - прост
   - добавляет лишнюю информацию, и если сеть к ней не готова, это приведёт к неправильному распознаванию

Возможны компромиссные варианты (ресайз + обрезка, реайз + вписывание) и тонкая настройка каждого метода. Можно попробовать располагать изображение в разных частях квадрата или заполнять шумом - в зависимости от сети всё может как помешать, так и помочь распознаванию.

Comment: Спасибо за довольно большой ответ! Сейчас подумал, а что если добавить нейроны, содержащую информацию о соотношении сторон изображения? Например, изображение 300x200:

2 нейрона:
a) 0.6667 - Соотношение сторон
b) 1 - Указывает на то, что большая сторона это ширина (если 0, то большая сторона - это высота) 

Само изображение можно вместить в квадрат, а дополнительную информацию (черные полосы) нейросеть будет убирать, исходя из переданных этих 2 нейронов.

Такой вариант возможен?

Comment: Скорее сеть будет считать чёрные полосы частью элемента; НС практически невозможно обучить игнорировать части картинки из-за одного-двух нейронов - вместо этого она учится игнорировать эту пару нейронов :) Есть архитектурный "хак": подать информацию о размере изображения ближе к концу, чтобы он мог повлиять на финальные выходы; но может проще сделать две сети - на квадратные и прямоугольные изображения, и ресайзить к той, где искажений меньше, если искажения настолько нежелательны? А вообще чаще сеть учат узнавать изображение независимо от его места на входе и с некоторыми искажениями

Comment: Хорошо, еще раз спасибо!)